# squid проблем с авторизацией

Tags: squid

Не могу авторизовать, ввожу логи и пароль нажимаю ок, а запрос на авторизацию снова появляется.
squid.conf

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/internet_users

acl all src all
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl SSL_ports port 443          # SSL
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 5190        # ICQ
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow ncsa_users
#Разрешим проксируемые порты
http_access deny all
http_port 8080
```

Пользователя создаю

```
htpasswd /etc/squid/internet_users test
```

Что не так?
Squid Cache: Version 3.5.12

Comment: Что в логе? Если пусто, то можно повысить детализацию логирования и повторить попытку. Когда увидите ошибку станет проще искать проблему.

Comment: Посмотрел по логам. FATAL: /etc/squid/internet_users: (13) Permission denied. Дал доступ и заработало, спасибо